# Binding Progressbar in xaml MVVM Pattern

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to implement a progress bar such that when I click on a search button, I need it to pop up. This is what I wrote, but for some reasons it shows up all the time. Any reply will be very appreciated.

The following is what I have in the xaml document:

```
<ProgressBar Name="searchProgressBar" IsIndeterminate="True" Width="200" Margin="10,10,0,0" Visibility="{Binding IsSearchbarVisible, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

And this is what I have in the VM.cs class:

```
private Visibility isSearchBarVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;
public Visibility IsSearchBarVisible
{
    get { return isSearchBarVisible; }
    set
    {
        isSearchBarVisible = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsSearchBarVisible");
    }
}

public ICommand OrderSearch
{
    get
    {
        if (_orderSearch == null)
        {
            _orderSearch = new RelayCommand(param =>
            {
                IsSearchBarVisible = Visibility.Visible;
                Console.WriteLine(isSearchBarVisible);
                int orderID;
                if(Int32.TryParse(param.ToString(), out orderID))
                    ShowMainOrderDetails(orderID);

                IsSearchBarVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;
                Console.WriteLine(isSearchBarVisible);
            });
        }
        return _orderSearch;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Visibility` in a ViewModel ? Argggggg

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: isn't the binding the issue in xaml IsSearchbarVisible (b is small) and in viewmodel IsSearchBarVisible(B is capital)

Answer (score 0):

Binding is the issue in xaml IsSearchbarVisible (b is small) and in viewmodel IsSearchBarVisible(B is capital)

Comment: Can you just try to set visibility, then sleep for a while and then set visibility to collapsed again? i.e removing console writes and showing main order details. Just to bottle neck the problem

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
private ICommand _onOrderSearchClickCommand;
public ICommand OnOrderSearchClickCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_onOrderSearchClickCommand != null) return _onOrderSearchClickCommand;
            _onOrderSearchClickCommand = new RelayCommand(OrderSearchButtonClick);
        return _onOrderSearchClickCommand;
    }
}
public void OrderSearchClick(object sender)
{
    IsSearchBarVisible = Visibility.Visible;
    Console.WriteLine(isSearchBarVisible);
    int orderID;
    if(Int32.TryParse(param.ToString(), out orderID))
        ShowMainOrderDetails(orderID);
}
```

And in the end of your method ShowMainOrderDetails(orderID) add in the end

> IsSearchBarVisible = Visibility.Hidden;